# How to bypass Excel popups when using VBA in PowerPoint to update msoLinkedOLEObject

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint with links from multiple Excel spreadsheets. I would like to update the linked object with a macro. 
The macro below will generate 2 types of popup. Popup will appear for each link to be updated in my case about 30 times. Clicking cancel will allow  macro to continue.
1)  Microsoft Excel has stopped working (close program)
2)  File in use (Read Only, Notify, or Cancel options)

Is there a way to bypass these messages?

```
Sub linkupdate()

Dim osld  As Slide
Dim oshp  As Shape

    For Each osld  In ActivePresentation.Slides
         For Each oshp  In osld.Shapes
            If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
              If LCase(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName) Like "*defect 95R*" Then
                   oshp.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual
                    oshp.LinkFormat.Update
                    oshp.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionAutomatic
              End If
            End If
         Next
      Next
  MsgBox "Finished updating Charts", , "Update Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`? In this case you'd probably need to drill down the the `Application` object from the OLE embedded one.

Comment: @Comintern thank you I believed setting displaysAlerts = false resolved the issue. This is what I did:                     xlApp.Workbooks.Open "xlFileNmae", ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=False   
xlApp.Workbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question - that's perfectly acceptable here and will help anyone else with the same issue that finds your question (comments are not exactly permanent here). Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

This code prevented the following alerts from occurring 
1) Microsoft Excel has stopped working (close program)
2) File in use (Read Only, Notify, or Cancel options)

After completion macro popup it can take a minute before the user gains control of PowerPoint. I'm assuming excel alerts are being closed in the background as there are over 30 link charts.

I'm a newbie at VBA so this code may not be efficient.

```
Sub linkUpdate()

Const xFile = "C:\temp\defect 95R.xlsx"
Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open xFile, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=False
xlApp.Workbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set pptPresentation = ActivePresentation
    'Loop through each slide in the presentation
    For Each osld In pptPresentation.Slides
        'Loop through each shape in each slide
         For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
           'Find out if the shape is a msoLinkedOLEObject type=10
            If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
              'Only update shape if file name contains defect 95r
              If LCase(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName) Like "*defect 95r*" Then
                   oshp.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual
                   xlApp.Workbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    oshp.LinkFormat.Update
                    oshp.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionAutomatic
              End If
            End If
         Next
      Next

xlApp.Workbooks.Close
xlApp.Workbooks.Application.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished updating Charts", , "Update Complete"
End Sub
```